# Java - MVC how to update right field with right value

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have set up my MVC so Controller knows who is the View and the Model. View knows the controller and finally Model knows the view through the addObserver method.

I am wondering how the view can update different fields with the right value by the update method.

**Model**

```
public void setDevise(String deviseCode) {
        System.out.println("Model setDevise = " + deviseCode);
        this.devise = ConvertisseurChange.Currency.fromValue(deviseCode);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(this.devise);
    }

public void setSomethingElse(String something) {
            System.out.println("Model something= " + something);
            this.something=something
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(this.something);
        }
```

**View**

```
@Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        //who called us and what did they send?
        System.out.println ("View      : Observable is " + o.getClass() + ", object passed is " + arg.getClass());
    }
```

The view is not supposed to knows about the model right? It only gets the changed objects by the update method. So how to make the view changed the "Devise" field with the right value and not the "Something" value.

Comment: use two methods: updateDevise and updateSomethingElse

Comment: Oh! and yes, the view knows about the model; it's the model that doesn't know about the view (except that it must be notified of any change).

Comment: Well I can't see how to call the view.updateDevise from the model. If the model doesn't know about view. Should the controller call those method after updating the model?

Comment: Instead of calling notifyObservers, you would call notifyObserversDevise or notifyObserversSomethingElse

Comment: Other option: pass an additional parameter telling which field was modified